# Display a generated qr code bitmap on webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, image-processing, bitmap

I am creating a asp.net (c#) web application and have the below code which references https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder. I wish to display a generated QR Code on a webpage on page load using an ID from the url.

However their example only shows how to do so in a windows form app with a picture box which can't be used in a web app.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string id = Request.Params["ID"];
        QRCoder.QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCoder.QRCodeGenerator();
        QRCoder.QRCodeGenerator.QRCode qrCode = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode("http://mywebsite.com/profile.aspx?ID="+ id+ "", QRCoder.QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.M);

        // pictureBoxQRCode.BackgroundImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);    //Can't use picture box in web app
        // I need to find the equivalent for a web app

    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is this a mvc or webfrom app ?

Comment: You could use the Base64 class of the library: https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder/blob/master/QRCoder/Base64QRCode.cs and then take the Base64 code and add it to your image tag as source.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time since I did webform stuff.
But since nobody else is answering:

why dont you use a javascript lib  like : http://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/ to generete the qrcode on the client side the has the added advantage of offloading the calculationt from te server to the client.

Comment: It's a webforms app, so I'm getting errors on the "public ActionResult qrCode (string id)
" and the filecontentresult